# fit-coefficient for non-linear function

Tags: regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression

I have a sigmoid (growth) function, in python:

```py
def sigmoid(x, centroid, k, amplitude = 1):
    y = amplitude / (1 + np.exp(k*(centroid-x)))
    return y
```

It is fitted by numerical methods (scipy.optimize.curvefit). What I am searching for is a simple parameter for how well the function describes the data, like r2 / spearman for linear functions. The best I have found (at least I thought so) is Maximal Information Coefficient (MIC).

What makes me doubt is that MIC is an indicator of the correlation between two variables, i.e. x and y instead of y and f(x). On the other hand, the expected relation between y and f(x) is

```py
y = f(x)
```

so that's a linear function and the traditional coefficients would be usable after all.

(If you conclude that I badly understand the matter, you are probably right. Please keep the explanation simple ...)

Comment: Is something wrong with mean squared error or mean absolute error?

Comment: Why not a simple plot? More informative ...

Comment: I have plots, 300 of them. I'd like it more consize than that.